# New to Jersey -- Getting Unsupported Media Type at Resource

Tags: json, rest, jax-ws, jersey

I'm new to Jersey and REST so please pardon if my question is too stupid. I have a simple resource called Places, and it should support a `GET` operation which returns some point of interest based on the input variable. Here are the input string and the class:

Error:

```
HTTP 415 - Unsupported Media Type
```

Input URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/RESTGO/rest/places?latitude=2&longitude=3&radius=3&types=food
```

Class:

```
@Path("/places")
public class Places {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONObject getPlaces(@QueryParam("latitude") double latitude,
            @QueryParam("longitude") double longitude,
            @QueryParam("radius") int radius,
            @QueryParam("types") String types,
            @DefaultValue("true") boolean sensor) {
        GooglePlacesClient google = new GooglePlacesClient();
        JSONObject json = null;

        try {
            String response = google.performPlacesSearch(latitude, longitude, radius, types, sensor);
            json = new JSONObject(response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you accepting `application/json` bodies? Set a http-header to application/json (name of the header: `Accept`, value = `application/json`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@DefaultValue` does not work without `@QueryParam`. Try adding the `@QueryParam` annotation to the `sensor`-argument (see [DefaultValue javadoc](http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/jax-rs/1.0/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html))

Answer (score 0):

please make sure rest [of the url] is mapped in your web.xml

```
http://localhost:8080/RESTGO/**`*rest*`**/places
```